# Mark records with error in a column for the file with a constant value for final dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a use case, where in if atleast one of the record has the value `err_present` in column `err` for a particular file, I would like to mark  rest of the records for same file as `bad_file` value  in dataframe.

Input Dataframe

```
+-----------+---------+
|err        |file_name|
+-----------+---------+
|err_present|f1       |
|           |f1       |
|           |f1       |
|           |f2       |
|           |f2       |
+-----------+---------+
```

Above dataframe has `err_present` for `f1` file_name column. So I want to mark the other rows containing `f1` with `bad_file` in final dataframe.

```
Desired output DF:
+--------+---------+
|err_present|file_name|
+--------+---------+--
|err_present|       f1|
|bad_file   |       f1|
|bad_file   |       f1|
|    null   |       f2|
|    null   |       f2|
+--------+---------+
```

Example Dataframe

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([('err_present', 'f1'), ('', 'f1'), ('', 'f1'),
                        ('', 'f2'), ('', 'f2')]
                       , ['err', 'file_name'])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#Isolate rows with err_present, rename err column and lit bad_file
s = df.where(col('err')=='err_present').withColumn('newerr',lit('bad_file')).drop('err')

(df.join(broadcast(s),how='left', on='file_name')#broadcast join new df from above to avaoid shuffle
 .withColumn('err', when(col('err')=='err_present',col('err')).otherwise(col('newerr')))#conditionally update err using new_err
 .drop('newerr')#drop unwated column
).show()



+---------+-----------+
|file_name|        err|
+---------+-----------+
|       f1|err_present|
|       f1|   bad_file|
|       f1|   bad_file|
|       f2|       null|
|       f2|       null|
+---------+-----------+
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `partition` by the `file_name` and create a new column called `err_present_in_group`  that is `True` if the string `"err_present"` is in that particular partition:

```
df.select("*", 
  F.max(
    (F.col('err') == 'err_present')
  ).over(Window.partitionBy('file_name')).alias('err_present_in_group')
).show()

+-----------+---------+--------------------+
|        err|file_name|err_present_in_group|
+-----------+---------+--------------------+
|err_present|       f1|                true|
|           |       f1|                true|
|           |       f1|                true|
|           |       f2|               false|
|           |       f2|               false|
+-----------+---------+--------------------+
```

Then our final `err_present` column can be determined by applying conditions based on the value in the `err` and `err_present` columns.

```
df.select("*", 
  F.max(
    (F.col('err') == 'err_present')
  ).over(Window.partitionBy('file_name')).alias('err_present_in_group')
).withColumn(
    'err_present',
    F.when(
        (F.col('err_present_in_group')) & (F.col('err') == 'err_present'), 
        F.lit('err_present')
    ).when(
        (F.col('err_present_in_group')) & (F.col('err') == ''), 
        F.lit('bad_file')
    ).otherwise(None)
).select(
    'err_present','file_name'
)

+-----------+---------+
|err_present|file_name|
+-----------+---------+
|err_present|       f1|
|   bad_file|       f1|
|   bad_file|       f1|
|       null|       f2|
|       null|       f2|
+-----------+---------+
```